# Selenium Webdriver C# :: CSS selector not working properly in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I am automating a website using Selenium C#. I am getting NoSuchElementException while trying to click element using CSS selector. But when I use xpath things are working. Can anyone help me understand why I am having this issue while using CSS selector.

Xpath value used.

`//*[@id="primary-navigation"]/ul/li[2]/a`

CSS Selector value used.

`#primary-navigation > ul > li:nth-child(2) > a`

Comment: `li:nth-child(n)` != `li[n]`

Answer (score 2):

xpaths `li[2]` gives you the second li element

css `li:nth-child(2)` gives you the li element that is the second child of its parent

for example

```
<ul>
  <p> something </p>
  <li> this will be returned </li>
</ul>
```

here xpath `li[2]` will return nothing (or an error/exception), cause there is only one li element

BUT css `li:nth-child(2)` will return the li element since it is the 2nd child of parent ul

So most probably the selectors are working properly, you just can't "translate" between xpath and css selectors "directly"